# Figure out the lengths of edges

Tags: geometry

I try to recreate the following:

[image]

Here is the link.
http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/cyclotomic-trapezoids-9-fold/

This might help (formula is uncorrected formatted here cause I don't know how to do that):

> each one the union of two triangles with edge lengths of the form
>   sin(k π/n).

So far I have figured out that there are 4 different lengths for the edges.
Here is a image of how P0 is split up:

[image]

a, b, c and d are edge lengths.
A, B, C etc. are corners.

The 2 long sides of shape P0 is `a` for example.
When splitting up `a` becomes `a+a+c`.

This is for all 4 edges:

`a = a+a+c
b = b+d
c = a+c+d
d = b+c+d`

They all depend on each other making it even harder.
Is there a way to figure the lengths out?

(more tags suggestion are welcome, I'm no math guru).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a limiting process. For that one just set up the substitution matrix

$$S=\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then use for starting vector say $v=(1, 1, 1, 1)^T$ and apply $S$ to it over and over again, i.e. consider
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S^n\ v$$
- when being normalized on the way - that ought approximate the relative lengths.

--- rk

Comment: I guess the **Dr.** in your name is well deserved.

Answer (score 0):

The shorter answer already is contained within the cited website. There it states that the tiles have side length of the form $\sin(\pi k/n)$ and the title further states "9-fold", i.e. $n=9$.

--- rk

Comment: Where does the _k_ stand for?